# How to check whether any shape exists?

Tags: excel, vba

How to check if any shape exists in sheet?

I have used below code:

```
Sub my()
    Dim shp As Shape
    If Not shp Is Nothing Then
        For Each shp In Sheet1.Shapes
            mesage = shp.TopLeftCell.Address(0, 0)
        Next shp
    Else
        mesage = Sheet1.Cells(1, 12).Address
    End If

End Sub
```

As I have not given shape name, it is executing 'else' part of 'If-else' loop.

I can't give shape name here as each time shape name is different.

Comment: `If Sheet1.Shapes.Count > 0 then` should suffice.

Comment: Thanks a lot Rory :)

Answer (score 13):

## Check if *any* Shapes exist

If you want to check whether there are *any* [VBA Shapes](https://learn.microsoft.com/office/vba/api/office.msoautoshapetype) on the active worksheet then you can simply check the value of the [`.Count` property](https://learn.microsoft.com/office/vba/api/excel.shapes.count) of the [`Shapes` object](https://learn.microsoft.com/office/vba/api/excel.shapes):

```
ActiveSheet.Shapes.Count
```

...which will return the number of shapes, or return **zero if there are no shapes**.

**Example Usage:**

```
If ActiveSheet.Shapes.Count = 0 Then MsgBox "No shapes found!"
```

---

## Check if *specific* Shape exists

If you need to check whether a ***specific*** shape exists, use this function:

```
Function shapeExists(shapeName As String) As Boolean
'returns TRUE if a shape named [ShapeName] exists on the active worksheet
    Dim sh As Shape
    For Each sh In ActiveSheet.Shapes
         If sh.Name = shapeName Then shapeExists = True
    Next sh
End Function
```

**Example usage:**

```
If Not shapeExists("My Shape Name") Then MsgBox "Shape not found!"
```

---

## *List All Shapes*

Lists all shapes on the active worksheet, in the Immediate window. (Hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> to open it.)

```
Sub ListAllShapes()
'list all shapes on the active worksheet
    Dim sh As Shape
    For Each sh In ActiveSheet.Shapes
        Debug.Print "id=" & sh.ID, "name=" & sh.Name
    Next sh
End Sub
```

---

## *Delete All Shapes*

Deletes all shapes from the active worksheet.

```
Sub DeleteAllShapes()
'delete all shapes on the active worksheet (Including CONTROLS, so use with caution!)
    Dim sh As Shape
    For Each sh In ActiveSheet.Shapes
        sh.Delete
    Next sh
End Sub
```

---

## More Information:

For more detailed information and examples of working with VBA Shapes, see my answers to other *Shape-related* questions (including *controls* which are just another kind of Shape):

- [**Pasted Shape not seen as “Latest” Shape**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51170453/8112776)
- [**Changing arc length in excel based on a cell value**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51797759/8112776)
- [**Can't add items to a combobox shape**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48957591/8112776)
- [**Overview of differences between Form Controls and ActiveX Controls in Excel**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50144021/8112776)
- [**How to use Events with Option Button Controls on UserForm**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49263001/8112776)
- [**How to disable right click menu of shapes**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47986210/8112776)

Comment: Good and elaborated answer, it's a pity it was not checked.  My 2 cents: in the function shapeExists above, I'd add an exit from the For loop once a shape was found.  No need to still cycle through all shapes.
...
If sh.Name = shapeName Then shapeExists = True : Exit For

Comment: shapeExists can be much quicker if you try to do something with the Shape in question and check the Error after that:
 On Error Resume Next: Debug.Print ActiveSheet.Shapes(shapeName).Name: If Err.NUMBER = 0 Then shapeExists = True Else shapeExists = False: On Error GoTo 0