# Disable right click menu of shapes

Tags: vba, excel

Is there a way to disable the right click menu for shapes like e.g. rectangles in VBA?

I tried:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
'    Application.WindowState = xlMaximized
    Application.DisplayFullScreen = True
    Application.CommandBars("Ply").Enabled = False
    Application.CommandBars("Shapes").Enabled = False
End Sub
```

but this does not seem to work.

Comment: Where is this sub located? Is it in your `This Workbook` object?

Comment: Yes it is in the ThisWorkbook object.. the other commands seem to work!

Comment: This is interesting. In this [link](http://www.vbaexpress.com/forum/showthread.php?12379-Solved-Hiding-Command-Toolbars) it looks like they're using `Workbook_Activate()` instead. Maybe try that?

Comment: no unfortunately also does not work

Answer (score 2):

The right-click menu (aka, *context menu*) is **not a Command Bar**.

You may know Command Bars by their older name, *Toolbars*, or their newer name, *Ribbons*.

Although you **can** [capture and/or disable a right-click event on a worksheet](https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/4291-excel-disable-right-click-menu.html#a1), this **doesn't apply** to objects like shapes.

However, you can prevent the context menu from showing by protecting the worksheet from changes (with or without a password).

If necessary you can allow some changes, but not others, to be made by the user.  More information at [this link](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Lock-or-unlock-specific-areas-of-a-protected-worksheet-75481b72-db8a-4267-8c43-042a5f2cd93a).

[image]

Comment: thank you for your reply - the problem however is that on the other hand i need to be able to select the shapes and also to generate them per vba.. when i protect the sheet neither is possible anymore..

Comment: When you need to creaye or manipulate the shapes via VBA, you can programmatically unprotect & reprotect the sheet as required.  Why do the users need to be able to select the shapes?  There's likely an alternative.

Comment: hm yeah you are right that should not be a problem with the creation of new shapes - but the selection of shapes is crucial to my program as i need to select various shapes to align them via vba..
basically i overwrite the left, or top values of the selected shapes with the value of the first selected shape..

Comment: Are there a limited number of shapes? If so, perhaps an alternate method of selecrion would work, like [static or dynamic] checkboxes...?  A screen  shot example of what you're doing might be helpful.

Comment: ....since unfortunately there's no built-in functionality for disabling only certain interactions with shapes. (Short of creating a custom add-on with C#)

Answer (score 0):

I have attached some screenshots of my application just to describe what I want to archive.

The problem is that the menu is realy annoying when trying to select more than one shape.

[image]

[image]

Comment: It is possible, but very very annoying with Excel :) , as you noticed.  Not sure, if Excel is the best program therefore at all.  MS Visio could be better suited.