# Open specific Workbook using Userform

Tags: vba, excel

I have a folder containing over 100 worksheets and named 1,2,3, etc but I can only open the workbooks by adding `.xlsx` to the number of the workbook in the combobox.

Is there a way to go around this?

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
   Dim filename As String
   Dim filepath As String

   filename = ComboBox1.Value
   filepath = "D:\e-library\MSC\DIS7000\data\"

   Workbooks.Open (filepath & filename)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes - you can get through that bu adding `.xlsx` to the filename programmatically instead of manually.
Try this:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
   Dim filename As String
   Dim filepath As String

   filename = ComboBox1.Value
   filepath = "D:\e-library\MSC\DIS7000\data\"

   Workbooks.Open (filepath & filename & ".xlsx")
End Sub
```

Comment: Also I have a detailed description of the difference between Form Controls and ActiveX controls [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49263001/8112776).