# Differences between Excel's Form Controls & ActiveX Controls

Tags: excel, vba, controls, activex, userform

Why are there **2 types of controls** available in Excel?  *(2 buttons, 2 combo boxes, 2 check box, etc...)*

What's the difference between  **Forms Controls** and **ActiveX Controls**?  Which one should I use?

[image]

Some code samples I find online work with my controls, but others do not.  How come?

How do I work with each type, and how can I tell the difference?

Comment: Came about this post through one of your comments. Makes a great cannonical!

Answer (score 49, accepted):

There is [eternal] confusion surrounding the **two** types of controls available to Excel — exacerbated by the contrasting *terminology* used by different online sources.

This is only a **general overview of the differences between *Form Controls* and *ActiveX Controls*** (based on my old notes that helped me finally figure out the differences!) Visit the included links for more detailed information about each control including code and sample projects.  ☺

<sup>(Adapted from my original post [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49258380/8112776) — now closed)</sup>

---

## Overview:

- There are **two** types of controls: **Form controls** and **ActiveX controls**:
- **Both** types of controls can be used on worksheets but **only ActiveX** controls can be used on **userforms**.
- **Form controls are part of the *Shapes* collection** (just like Drawing Objects), and thus are referred to like:   [image: worksheet . Shapes(" controlname ")]
- ActiveX controls are basically part of the worksheet and are therefore referred to like:
  [image: worksheet . controlname]
- **Both** types of controls can be created, modified and deleted from either the worksheet, or programmatically with VBA, however, the 2 types of controls have slightly varying syntax when using VBA to refer to them.
- Some sites discuss also discuss a **Data Form**. This is **nothing more than a userform** made specifically for data entry/manipulation of data, so it would've made more sense to call them (the more familiar sounding) ***"Data Entry Userform"***.
- Office documentation also occasionally refers to a **worksheet** as a form.  While this is *technically* correct, don't let this confuse you. Think of the word "form" as being used in a *general sense*:

[image: dictionary image: form]

---

## Two Types of Controls

1. **Form Controls**
2. **ActiveX Controls**

The two look, behave, and are controlled similarly, but not identically. (List [here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/overview-of-forms-form-controls-and-activex-controls-on-a-worksheet-15ba7e28-8d7f-42ab-9470-ffb9ab94e7c2).)

For example, let's compare the two types of **Combo Boxes**.  In some programming languages, comparable controls are referred to as a *"drop-down menu"* or *"drop-down list"*. In Excel, we have a *"**Form Control Combo Box**"*, and an *"**ActiveX Control Combo Box**"*:

[image: compare control types]  <sup>(Click image to enlarge.)</sup>

☆ <sub>"Default name" applies to controls created *manually*.  Controls created programmatically do not have (or require) a default name and therefore should have one assigned immediately upon creation.</sub>

---

[image: differences between controls]

<sup>(Source: [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48957591/8112776))</sup>

---

### Control Availability

This image below shows which common controls are *generally* available for use in Worksheets and User Forms.

[image: chart of controls]

Other factors may affect control availability.

- Office.com : [Why are form-related commands or controls on the ribbon disabled?](https://support.office.com/article/why-are-form-related-commands-or-controls-on-the-ribbon-disabled-80be06a7-45d9-4582-9544-dfe87ecb9494)
- Office.com : [Overview of forms, Form controls, and ActiveX controls on a worksheet](https://support.office.com/article/overview-of-forms-form-controls-and-activex-controls-on-a-worksheet-15ba7e28-8d7f-42ab-9470-ffb9ab94e7c2)
- MSDN : [Add Controls to a User Form](https://msdn.microsoft.com/vba/excel-vba/articles/add-controls-to-a-user-form)

---

> ## About ActiveX controls and related Security Concerns
>
> <sup>An ActiveX control is an *extension* to the VBA Toolbox. You use ActiveX controls just as you would any of the standard built-in controls, such as the CheckBox control. When you add an ActiveX control to an application, it becomes part of the development and run-time environment and provides new functionality for your application.</sup>
>
> - <sup>An ActiveX control is implemented as an in-process server (typically a small object) that can be used in any OLE container. Note that the full functionality of an ActiveX control is available only when used within an OLE container designed to be aware of ActiveX controls.</sup>
> - <sup>This container type, called a *control container* or ***control object***, can operate an ActiveX control by using the control’s properties and methods, and receives notifications from the ActiveX control in the form of events. The following figure demonstrates this interaction:</sup>
>
>   [image: example]
>   <sub><sup>(**Source**: [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa733733(v=vs.60).aspx) and [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa268985(v=vs.60).aspx))</sup></sub>

**See also:**

- Wikipedia: [**ActiveX**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ActiveX)
- Symantec.com : [**Discussion of ActiveX Vulnerabilities**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n5Nj2.png)
- How-To Geek : [**What ActiveX Controls Are and Why They’re Dangerous**](https://www.howtogeek.com/162282/what-activex-controls-are-and-why-theyre-dangerous/)

---

### Option Buttons (Radio Buttons)

In Excel, the two types of radio buttons are actually called **Option Buttons**.  To further confuse matters:

- the default name for the form control is `OptionButton1`.
- the default name for the ActiveX control is `Option Button 1`.

A good way to distinguish them is by opening the control's Properties list (on the ribbon under the Development tab, or by right-clicking the control and choosing `Properties`, or hitting <kbd>F4</kbd>), because the ActiveX control has many more options that the simpler form control.

> **Option buttons and checkboxes** can be bound together (so only one option at a time can be selected from the group) by placing them in a shared **Group Box**.
>
> Select the group box control and then hold <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> while selecting each of the other controls that you want to group. Right-click the group box control and choose `Grouping` → `Group`.

The first two links below are separate sets of instructions for handling each type of option button.

---

## HANDLING CONTROL EVENTS:

### Form control events (`Click` event only)

Form control events are only able to respond to one event: **the `Click` event**.  (More info [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/outlook-vba/articles/control-events).)  Note that **this section doesn't apply to userforms** since they use only ActiveX controls.

**To add a procedure for the `Click` event:**

- Right-click the control and choose `Assign Macro...`
- In the 'Assign Macro` Dialog:
- Select an existing procedure, and click <kbd>OK</kbd>, *or,*
- Create a new procedure in the VBE by clicking <kbd>New...</kbd>, *or,*
- Record a new macro by clicking <kbd>Record...</kbd>, *or,*
- to Remove the assigned event, delete its name from `Macro Name` field and click <kbd>OK</kbd>.

  [image: assign events] <sup>(Click image to enlarge.)</sup>

To rename, edit or delete existing macros, hit <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F8</kbd> to open the `Macro` interface:

[image: Macros dialog]

---

### ActiveX control events

ActiveX controls have a **more extensive list** of events to which they can be set up to respond.

To assign events to ActiveX controls, right-click the control and choose `View Code`.  In the VBE, you can paste in code, or **choose specific events** from the drop-down list at the top-right of the VBE window.

[image: activeX events]  <sup>(Click image to enlarge.)</sup>

### **Control event handling on a userform:**

Events can also be used in controls on userforms.  Since only ActiveX controls can be placed a userform, you'll have the "more coding + more functionality" trade-off.

ActiveX controls are added to userforms the same way as they are added to a worksheet. Keep in mind that any events assigned to the userform *itself* (ie., background) will be "blocked" in any areas covered up by a control, so you may need to assign the same events to the controls as well as the userform.

**For example**, in order to make this userform respond to `MouseMove` ***anywhere on the form***, the same event code was applied to *the userform, textboxes, option buttons and the frame*:

[image: A userform with controls responding to events]

---

## VBA EXAMPLES

### Add/Modify/Delete a form control option button using VBA:

```
Sub formControl_add()
    'create form control
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ActiveSheet
    With ws.Shapes.AddFormControl(xlOptionButton, 25, 25, 100, 100)
        .Name = "cOptionButton1"  'name control immediately (so we can find it later)
    End With
End Sub

Sub formControl_modify()
    'modify form control's properties
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ActiveSheet
    ws.Shapes("cOptionButton1").Select
    With Selection 'shapes must be Selected before changing
        .Characters.Text = "wxyzabcd"
   End With
End Sub

Sub formControl_delete()
    'delete form control
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ActiveSheet
    ws.Shapes("cOptionButton1").Delete
End Sub
```

- [Shapes.AddShape Method (Excel)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/shapes-addshape-method-excel)
- [Shape Properties (Excel)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn301031.aspx)
- [Characters Object (Excel)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/characters-object-excel)

---

### Add/Modify/Delete an ActiveX command button using VBA:

```
Sub activexControl_add()
    'create ActiveX control
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ActiveSheet
    With ws.OLEObjects.Add("Forms.CommandButton.1")
        .Left = 25
        .Top = 25
        .Width = 75
        .Height = 75
        .Name = "xCommandButton1" 'name control immediately (so we can find it later)
    End With
End Sub

Sub activexControl_modify()
    ' modify activeX control's properties
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ActiveSheet
    With ws.OLEObjects("xCommandButton1").Object
        .Caption = "abcxyz"
        .BackColor = vbGreen
    End With
End Sub

Sub activexControl_delete()
    ' delete activeX control
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ActiveSheet
    ws.OLEObjects("xCommandButton1").Delete
End Sub
```

- [OLEObjects.Add Method (Excel)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/oleobjects-add-method-excel)
- [BackColor, ForeColor Properties (ActiveX Controls)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa443172(v=vs.60).aspx)

---

### Add/Remove items from a form control combo box:

```
Sub ComboBox_addRemoveItems_FormControl()

    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ActiveSheet

    'add item to form control combo box
    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Shapes("Drop Down 1").ControlFormat.AddItem "abcd"

    'remove all items from from form control combo bo
    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Shapes("Drop Down 1").ControlFormat.RemoveAllItems

End Sub
```

---

### Add/Remove items from an ActiveX combo box:

```
Sub ComboBox_addRemoveItems_ActiveXControl()

    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ActiveSheet

    'add items to ActiveX combo box
    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").ComboBox1.AddItem "abcd"

    'remove all items from ActiveX combo box
    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").ComboBox1.Clear

End Sub
```

---

## More Information:

- Office.com : [Add a checkbox or option button (**Form controls**)](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/add-a-check-box-or-option-button-form-controls-9f201e46-8f6b-4a9d-a320-f44b28088cb0)
- Office.com : [Add a checkbox, option button, or toggle button (**ActiveX controls**)](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/add-a-check-box-option-or-toggle-button-activex-controls-2f0c62f5-af64-49cd-aec6-de018647cae3)
- Office.com : [**Overview of forms, Form controls, and ActiveX controls on a worksheet**](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/overview-of-forms-form-controls-and-activex-controls-on-a-worksheet-15ba7e28-8d7f-42ab-9470-ffb9ab94e7c2)
- Office.com : [**Enable selection through choice controls** (check and list boxes)](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/enable-selection-through-choice-controls-check-and-list-boxes-c3616c0a-a898-4259-b8cc-06445349956c)
- Office.com : [**Add, edit, find, and delete rows by using a data form**](https://support.office.com/article/add-edit-find-and-delete-rows-by-using-a-data-form-17bca0a4-3ba5-444a-983c-a8ce70609374)
- MSDN : [**VBA Shape Members**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff193908(v=office.14).aspx)
- MSDN : [**Using ActiveX Controls on Sheets** (Office)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb211430(v=office.12).aspx)
- Exceldemy : [**How to Use Form Controls in Excel**](https://www.exceldemy.com/how-to-use-form-controls-in-excel/)
- MSDN : [**Using Windows Forms Controls on Excel Worksheets** (Visual Studio)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb157869.aspx)
- Microsoft TechNet : [**Behaviour of ActiveX controls embedded in Office documents**](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/srd/2009/03/03/behavior-of-activex-controls-embedded-in-office-documents/)
- Stack Overflow : [**What is the difference between “Form Controls” and “ActiveX Control” in Excel 2010?**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15455179/8112776)

Comment: This is beautiful. Thank you! 

Comment: @ashleedawg Very impressed by your deep knowledge of VBA concepts and clarity of explanation. I finally understood the difference between activeX and form controls!
I'd give you 100 point if I could...