# VBA-Excel Button not showing, running several modules

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to create a button that run filters through my data. I would  like to customize the size, name (through vba) but I can not get my button to show up. Not too sure what is missing.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)


End Sub
Public Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Call Module1.Main
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what the problem is. If in the same workbook and you want to call a sub from different locations declare its scope `Public`.

For example if I have the following in `sheet1` code pane:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
End Sub
Public Sub CommandButton1_Click()
   Test1
   Test2
   Test3
End Sub

Public Sub Test1()    
    MsgBox "Test1"    
End Sub
```

And in module 1

```
Public Sub Test2()   
    MsgBox "Test2"    
End Sub
```

And in module 2

```
Public Sub Test3()    
    MsgBox "Test3"   
End Sub
```

Everything runs fine from the `CommandButton1_Click` due to the Public scope declarations.

Notes:

1. `Call` is obsolete and not needed here
2. Prefix of the module name shouldn't be needed either I think
3. The `CommandButton1_Click` would go in the code pane of the sheet containing the button.

Edit:

If you are after adding a button and positioning it I would refer you to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50144020/overview-of-differences-between-form-controls-and-activex-controls-in-excel) which lists the different methods. If you find that useful please remember to upvote the author.

An example from that, regarding adding an ActiveX and positioning is as follows:

```
Sub activexControl_add()
    'create ActiveX control
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ActiveSheet
    With ws.OLEObjects.Add("Forms.CommandButton.1")
        .Left = 25
        .Top = 25
        .Width = 75
        .Height = 75
        .Name = "xCommandButton1" 'name control immediately (so we can find it later)
    End With
End Sub
```

From my own code samples I have an example where, due to users having different screen resolutions, my ActiveX objects were moving, so I put the following in the workbook open event to ensure the buttons were where I wanted them and sized as I wanted them:

```
 With wsCCGOverview '<== sheet containing combobox control (this could be your button)

          .OLEObjects("ComboBox1").Left = 296.25
          .OLEObjects("ComboBox1").Width = 132.75
          .OLEObjects("ComboBox1").Height = 40
          .OLEObjects("ComboBox1").Top = 187.5
          .Shapes("ComboBox1").ScaleHeight 1.25, msoFalse, msoScaleFromTopLeft

End With
```

Comment: the modules are not tests and I can not get them running without calling them this way. Regarding the command Button, my issue is that it is not showing up. I tried changing a few things like in your approach, but it didn't change anything

Comment: You realise that you have to either programmatically add the button or add it via the developer tab before clicking?

Comment: maybe I didn't phrase my question correctly. My question is through VBA-Excel, how do i show my button and customize the size etc. I apologies for the confusion

Comment: Ok. So are you adding a button to the worksheet or a form?

Comment: This link runs through adding different types of buttons in different places https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50144020/overview-of-differences-between-form-controls-and-activex-controls-in-excel

Comment: Is it an activex or form control button you are adding?

Comment: It's an activex button, I will give that a try, thank you

Comment: Ok. The above edit shows you how to add an activex through code and position. I guess what I don't understand is why you don't go to the developer tab and > controls > add activex command button and place it where you want. Click the design mode button on developer tab so you can resize the button manually. Or have I missed something? Apologies if I have.

Comment: Because I am working with a large amount of data and I have some settings turned off. If I were to add the button through GUI then it will slow down my upload at a certain point. If it comes down to it, I will try it that way. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Ok. Well the above and the link given should help.