# How to make two columns in a combobox?

Tags: excel, vba

There are two columns in his list, but after I select one item from the list, he does not show me 2 columns. How do I do that even after I choose the figure, will he continue to show me the full text of the two columns?

Comment: Hi and welcome to the forum. Please read this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

If you're using an **ActiveX Combo Box control**, click the control then click <kbd>Properties</kbd> on the Ribbon (under `Developer`) and change the property called `Column Count` as needed.

The ActiveX control is added with the button circled in Green in the image below.  The red circle is a Form Control Combo Box, which does not have a property for number of columns.

(If the <kbd>Properties</kbd> button is disabled, make sure the <kbd>Design Mode</kbd> button on the ribbon is "on", then right-click your control.)

Note that you'll also have to set "Column Widths", for example `3;3` for two 3cm-wide columns. (or two 3 inch wide columns depending where you are.)  There's more information about all of this, and examples, in the links below and elsewhere online.

[image: img]

<sup>(Sorry if it looks like an [American football play diagram](https://buidln.clipdealer.com/001/325/900//previews/16--1325900-Football%20Play%20on%20White.jpg)... I almost missed circling a step so I added it oout-of-order, can you tell which one?!  :-)  Let me know if you have any questions...)</sup>

---

### More Information:

- Stack Overflow : [**Differences between *Form Controls* and *ActiveX Controls* in Excel**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50144020/8112776)
- ExtendOffice : [**How to display multiple columns in combo box?**](https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/4022-excel-combobox-multiple-columns.html)
- YouTube : [**Excel VBA UserForm Combobox with Multiple Columns**](https://youtu.be/LlE1u7coRVc)

Comment: thank you very much for the quick answer
Of course I set the columncount as you indicated. But it only affects the drop-down list, and it does not affect the cell itself, for example