# VBA Checkbox range to Table

Tags: vba, excel

I have a form with 13 checkboxes. I have it setup so that if it is checked, a cell is marked as either TRUE or FALSE.

What I'm trying to do is export the data from the form into a table. I have everything else finished, however I'm confused on how to input the checkbox values better.

Rather than doing this if statement for all the checkbox's

```
If CHECKBOX = TRUE Then
    CHECKBOX_VAL = string
End If

If CHECKBOX2 = TRUE Then
    CHECKBOX_VAL2 = string2
End If

table_object_row.Range(x,x).Value = CHECKBOX_VAL
table_object_row.Range(x,x).Value = CHECKBOX_VAL2
```

How can I simply export the TRUE values of the checkbox to the table. Should I be using an array to store only the True values?

Answer (score 0):

You can loop through the controls on your userform, and if the element is of type `CheckBox` then place in your array, table, or whatever.

```
Dim ctl
For Each ctl In UserForm1.Controls  'the controls collection of your userform
    If TypeName(ctl) = "CheckBox" Then

        Debug.Print "The value of " & ctl.Name & " is " & ctl.Value
        '(do something with your values here)

    End If
Next ctl
```

---

### More Information:

- Stack Overflow : [**Overview of differences between Form Controls & ActiveX Controls**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50144020/8112776)
- MSDN : [**Controls Collection** (Microsoft Forms)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/controls-collection-microsoft-forms)
- ExcelEasy : [**Controls Collection**](https://www.excel-easy.com/vba/examples/controls-collection.html)
- ozgrid : [**Loop Through Controls on a UserForm**](http://www.ozgrid.com/VBA/control-loop.htm)