# Dynamically populate Combobox with colum content - time error 424

Tags: excel, vba

I'm very new to DBA so probably it's a banal mistake but I looked around and I did not found anything that could help me.
I'm trying to populate a combobox dynamically using the content of a column (column "A" in this specific case) using a macro linked to a button. If the analyzed cells are empty everything goes smoothly and the message "done!" appears, but if there is any data in the cells I get the error "424 object required access".
I don't know if it would help: I took the code from this youtube video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=x8O59GtatH8 and adapted it (just removed the listox) the complete code is at 5.35

I'm probably misunderstanding something very basic. I am guessing the declaration of the combobox.

```
Sub prova_stessa_scheda()

row_review = 1

    Dim TheSheet As Worksheet
    Set TheSheet = Sheets("Listino_prezzi")




   Do

   DoEvents

   row_review = row_revieew + 1

   item_in_review = TheSheet.Range("A" & row_review)

    If Len(item_in_review) > 0 Then ComboProva_Change.AddItem (item_in_review) 'this is the command that gives the error

    Loop Until item_in_review = ""

    MsgBox "Done!"




End Sub
```

I expected that when the macro gets triggered the combobox gets filled with the value written in the cells of column "A" instead I got the error 424.

Comment: Where does your code live - is it code of a form or a module? Is the name of the Combobox really `ComboProva_Change`?  Put a statement `Option Explicit` at the top of your code - if you have a misspelling of the name, the compiler will tell you.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to specify it, the code lives in a module. I'm feeling dumb now, the name of the Combobox is CombProva (the name that you see if you right-click on the combobox and go on properties right?) I took the wrong name from another code. However I  if I had Option Explicit I got the error "Variable Not Defined Compiler Error" the line "Sub prova_stessa_scheda()" get highlighted.  thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you put your code into the Worksheet module of the sheet where the combobox is placed, VBA is assuming that you want to access the element `CombProva` of that sheet (this is what is done in the video, only with different names).

However, if you put your code into a regular module, VBA does not know what `CombProva` is. You have to tell VBA that you want to access it from a specific sheet. There are several ways to do so:

**(1)** Use

```
With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Listino_prezzi")
   .ComboProva.AddItem (item_in_review)
End With
```

Note that the following code will throw an compiler error. This is because `TheSheet` is of type `Worksheet`, so it could be any worksheet, and a worksheet does not have anything named `ComboProva`.

```
Dim TheSheet As Worksheet
Set TheSheet = Sheets("Listino_prezzi")
With TheSheet 
   .ComboProva.AddItem (item_in_review)     ' <-- Compiler error
End With
```

**(2)** You can access the sheet also by its *CodeName*. If you look to the video: The sheet itself was renamed to `Admin Site`, but the CodeName is still `Sheet1` (the CodeName can only be changed in the VBA editor in the Property-window). So you can write

```
With Sheet1
   .ComboProva.AddItem (item_in_review)
End With
```

**(3)** You can access the combobox by name from the `Shapes`-collection of the sheet (basically everything that is put on a sheet but not within an cell is a `Shape`). However, as you are dealing with `ActiveX`-controls, this is a little bit ugly.

```
Dim sh as Shape
Set sh = TheSheet.Shapes("ComboProva")
With sh.DrawingObject.Object
    Call .AddItem("Variante x")
End With
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, I tried all 3 methods more time but it doesn't work yet, it gave me the same error (of course it must be  something very silly that I do wrong). Where do you have to put the code that ou gave me or what I need to substitute? I double checked the name of the combobox, so that's not the problem. Thank you very much for the help an patince.

Comment: Can it be that you inserted a Form Control rather than a Active X Control? See https://stackoverflow.com/q/15455179/7599798 - or really detailed https://stackoverflow.com/a/50144021/7599798

Comment: Yes! That was the problem! I know that was something silly! Thanks for the help and knolage that you gave me!