# Excel VBA: Populate combobox (userform type) from array

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to do something (I think) easy, but I can't find it.

At the start of my Excel file I add the string values from the array (which is created meanwhile because you can't define a const string array):

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    CompleteAddList
End Sub
```

/

```
Public Function CompleteAddList(
    For Each a In ArrAddList
        With ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet 1").Shapes("AddList1").ControlFormat
            .List = a         
        End With
    MsgBox (a)
    Next a
End Function
```

/

```
Public Function ArrAddList()
    ArrAddList = Array("Text1", "Text2")
End Function
```

I see the message boxes, but the data is not stored in the combobox (it's still empty).
Is this because it's in a public function ? Or is it just not correct the way I wrote it?

Comment: Is it a "userform" type, or a sheet Form type (Drop Down)?

Comment: It's a "form control" type, the second from the top left here on the image: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50144020/differences-between-excels-form-controls-activex-controls

Comment: OK. Got it. Anyhow, I tried posting two pieces of code able to deal with both sheet combo boxes...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please, test the next code. It assumes that the combo in discussion is a Form type:

```
Sub testDropDownFill()
  Dim sh As Worksheet, cb As DropDown, ArrAddList
  
  Set sh = Sheets("Sheet 1") 'take care of the space between Sheet and 1
  Set cb = sh.DropDowns("AddList1")
  ArrAddList = Array("Text1", "Text2")
  cb.list = ""
  cb.list = ArrAddList
End Sub
```

If the combo in discussion is an ActiveX type, plese use the next code:

```
Sub testComboActXFill()
  Dim sh As Worksheet, cb As MSForms.ComboBox, ArrAddList
  
  Set sh = Sheets("Sheet 1") 'take care of the space between Sheet and 1
  Set cb = sh.OLEObjects("ComboBox1").Object
  ArrAddList = Array("Text1", "Text2")
  cb.Clear
  cb.list = ArrAddList
End Sub
```

Comment: @smirnoff103 Glad I could help!