# Loading combobox list items

Tags: excel, vba, userform

i would like to add a list of numbers to a userform combobox depending on a cell value eg

| item | qty |
| --- | --- |
| tables | 2 |
| chairs | 4 |

(userform control) combobox_tables (items) 0,1,2

(userform control) combobox_chairs (items) 0,1,2,3,4

i cannot figure this out im guessing the easiest would be a loop added to an array but im still learning VBA
any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Excel VBA: Populate combobox (userform type) from array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68270790/excel-vba-populate-combobox-userform-type-from-array)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming it's a form control (and not a data validation drop down):

```
Dim tables As Variant, Dim chairs As Variant, Dim tablebox As Shape
Dim chairbox As Shape, Dim i As Integer

tables = Array(0, 1, 2)
chairs = Array(0, 1, 2, 3, 4)

Set tablebox = Worksheets("Worksheet1").Shapes("combobox_Tables")
Set chairbox = Worksheets("Worksheet1").Shapes("combobox_Chairs")

For i = 0 To UBound(tables)
     tablebox.ControlFormat.AddItem tables(i)
Next i

For i = 0 To UBound(chairs)
     chairbox.ControlFormat.AddItem chairs(i)
Next i
```

Note: If you have the data in the arrays in some cells of your worksheet, you can use .ListFillRange = "A1:A2" to achieve the same thing in one line.