# Dynamically Changing Arc Length based on Cell Value (Excel)

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to adjust the arc length in Excel based on the value of a specific cell.

For example, if the % = 100, then the arc should become a circle.

The code I'm using is not working. The Arc length of (Block Arc 1) doesn't change when I change the % value in the cell (A1). Can anyone help please :) ?

```
Sub AdjustArc(arcShape As Shape, percent As Single)
    Dim xAddress As String
    On Error Resume Next
    If Target.CountLarge = 1 Then
        xAddress = Target.Address(0, 0)
        If xAddress = "A1" Then
            AdjustArc ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Shapes("Block Arc 1"), Val(Target.Value)
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: You can format your code block by clicking to [edit] your question, then select (highlight) the section that is code, then hit Ctrl+G or click the `{ }` button. ;)

Comment: Thanks @ashleedawg - I've edited it

Comment: What does 'not working' mean? If you were answering this question, what would you like to know?

Comment: @nicomp, I mean that the Arc length of (Block Arc 1) doesn't change when I change the % value in the cell (A1)

Comment: you may want to show your current whole code and scenario.

Comment: @DisplayName - This is the only code I have. I just want to represent some progress% with Arc which its length change based on the %. I'm just a beginner :(

Comment: your shown code has a `Sub AdjustArc(arcShape As Shape, percent As Single)` calling itself (`AdjustArc ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Shapes("Block Arc 1"), Val(Target.Value)`)

Comment: theoretically I understand what you're saying, but could you help by recommending what to modify.

Comment: theoretically you should have an `AdjustArc()` sub that acts on a shape: you must show it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I saw your [previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51797109/changing-arc-length-in-excel-based-on-a-cell-value).

You should need something like follows

1. `Worksheet_Change` event handler

   place the following code in the code pane of the worksheet where the arc shape resides (and be sure the the shape is named after "Block Arc 1")

   ```
   Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
       If Target.CountLarge = 1 Then
           If Target.Address(0, 0) = "A1" Then AdjustArc Shapes("Block Arc 1"), Target.Value
       End If
   End Sub
   ```
2. `AdjustArc` sub

   place the AdjustArc() sub (@ashleedawg 's courtesy) in any module you want

   ```
   Sub AdjustArc(arcShape As Shape, percent As Single)
   ' ashleedawg 's courtesy in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51797109/changing-arc-length-in-excel-based-on-a-cell-value
   'adjust the circumference of the arc or hides if 0%.
   'Supply the percent as a fraction between 0 and 1. (50% = 0.5)

       With arcShape
           If percent <= 0 Then 'hide shape
               .Visible = False
               Exit Sub
           End If

           If percent > 1 Then percent = 1 'over 100%, make it 100%
           .Visible = True

           '0 = Full Circle, 359.9 = sliver, 360 = Full Circle
           .Adjustments.Item(1) = (1 - percent) * 359.9
       End With
   End Sub
   ```

Comment: It works perfectly. Thanks a lot of your assistance.

Comment: You are welcome. Still wondering why you didn’t attach your full previuos code...